# Prove that a set $G$ is equal to $\operatorname{int}(\Omega)$ given that $G \subset \Omega$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, normed-spaces

given $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n} $ an open set and given $ G \subset \mathbb{R}^{n} $ , also open, such that $ \operatorname{int}(\Omega) \subset G \subset \Omega$. Prove that $G= \operatorname{int}(\Omega)$

I start demonstrating that $G \subset \Omega$ giving that $z \in G$ and $\beta_{\rho}(x) \subset \Omega $ and $\beta_{\delta}(y) \subset \beta_{\rho}(x) $:

$\lVert z-x \rVert = \lVert z-y+y-x \rVert \\ \leq \lVert z-y \rVert + \lVert y-x \rVert \\= \delta -\lVert x-y\rVert+||y-x \rVert \\ \Rightarrow z \in \beta_{\rho}(x)
$

But I'm not sure if the proof is right so far. And I have no idea how to continue the demonstration that $G=\operatorname{int}(\Omega)$.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you know that if $\Omega$ is open then $\mathrm{int}\, \Omega = \Omega$?

Comment: Actually I want to proof that $G=int(\Omega)$

Comment: Use the fact that the interior of a set is the union of all open sets contained in the set.

Comment: You are assuming that $\Omega$ is open, which by definition means $\Omega = int(\Omega)$.  You are further assuming $int(\Omega) \subset G \subset \Omega$ which then reads $int(\Omega) \subset G \subset int(\Omega)$.